# Making a SharePoint 365 summary table

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

OFFICE 365: I am trying to generate an Inventory Summary table (list) with data the comes from three other SharePoint lists on the same site.  I have a Procurement list, Inventory Receipt List, and an Inventory Usage list.

In the procurement list, I need to identify the number of unique entries to populate the Summary table, then load the total number ordered for each item. To that record, I need to add the total number received for each item from the Inventory Receipt list. Then I need to bring in the total number of each item used from the Inventory Usage list. From that I can calculate the number on hand and the number to be procured.

I have tried going through the Workflow option, but this is all new to me and I haven't been able to connect the dots. I was planning on using SPD, but I can't get the required access level to open the site in SPD. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a modern or classic SharePoint Online?

Comment: This is for SharePoint 365

Comment: I understand it's SharePoint Online, but sites can be either the classic or modern experience: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-classic-and-modern-experiences-5725c103-505d-4a6e-9350-300d3ec7d73f

Comment: Sorry, it is the modern experience

Comment: If all you just want to do with the summary list is to show the reports and if you are comfortable with Power Bi, you could create a power bi report that shows the quantity ordered, inventory status, etc.

Comment: I hadn't thought of Power BI. Not something that I have used very much and I'm not sure that we have access to it, but I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your list is designed to be as:

[image]

Access to SharePoint designer requires a contribute permission level.

If your permissions are not sufficient, I recommend that you create a few look up columns in the summary list.

Get the values from the columns in the different lists, and then create a calculated column to calculate their values.

Comment: I did consider using look-ups, the issue is that it requires user action and isn't automated fully. The user would have to select the item to update the table. 
Also, since this is a running inventory, each of those tables may have multiple line items for the same items. So the content is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I decided the best path forward was to create three separate flows related to the three lists that feed the summary.

Populate Summary - This flow will take data from the procurement data entered into the table and move it to the summary list.

Item Received - This flow will take the number of items received and load it into the summary table for the inventory that was received.

Items Used - This flow will take the number if items used and add to the summary table for the inventory that was received.

The other fields are calculated fields based on the data provided by these flows.